# Deployment from Maven repository to destr servers

Tags: java, maven, deployment, puppet

My question might be trivial, but I haven't found any meaningful answer.

I have multi-modules application which is built and deployed to Maven repository. Now I would like to have a framework/script which will be triggered by Jenkins/Bamboo and will do the following:

1. take already built and signed application artifacts from Maven repository
2. Deploy them on remote servers using given set of rules/configs
3. Deploy dependencies as well
4. Form startup scripts for application with correct classpath

Approaches I've seen included custom set of bash scripts, but the question is always dependencies. Since dependencies are already part of pom.xml I don't want to declare them again set of scripts.

Ideally I would like to re-use the same pom.xml to download dependencies and artifacts to servers. Also I'm looking towards more or less standard deployment based on Puppet.

I have two constraints:

1. Maven based deployments don't work since I would like to deploy both application (my) and third-party artifacts from Maven repo.
2. Building jar-with-dependeincies using assembly plugin is not an option as well

Could you please suggest something?

Thank you!

Comment: Why does the deployment not work cause you have 3rd party deps ? So where is exactly the problem?

Comment: Taking into accounts suggestions below, maybe I just not sure how to use it properly.
I meant I would like to omit building project every time before deployment

Comment: @AntonPolyakov See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26452864/1744774). No building there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

You're right that maven already has all the dependency info. I would add an extra maven module that will depend on all other modules, so maven runs it last. I would also define this module under a profile that only your CI server runs.

In this module, I'd use either a custom maven plugin, or the maven groovy plugin and some (inline?) Groovy code to generate your deployment scripts. Both of these approaches get you access to mavens project model, which has all of your dependencies

Comment: Hi! Thank you. So if I understood correctly, your new mvn module will be built on CI server, then it can be packed and bundled to the prod servers. Is that how it should be?

Comment: @AntonPolyakov - this extra maven module can either just produce the deployment scripts, which jenkins can then run using a post-build job, or can do the actual deployment (you can set env vars on jenkins which it can pick up as configuration) - depends on how you want to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd:

1. make the servers Jenkins nodes (JVM and `slave.jar` is all that you need for that)
2. create "establish runtime environment" jobs that are configured to run on specific servers (with 1. aka Jenkins nodes or slaves then)

   1. define scripts in these jobs that run on the servers then and do your stuff there
   2. **or better, avoid scripts, mavenize it:**

      1. install Maven on the servers
      2. create "establish runtime environment" POMs on the servers which:

         1. download runtime artifacts from your repository (including <dependencies>)
         2. establish and configure your runtime environments accordingly

Comment: Thank you, this sounds like a way to go if you have access directly to your servers from Jenkins. What if you don't?

Comment: @AntonPolyakov: Establish access. ;-) What do you mean by "What if you don't?"? You wrote "2. Deploy them on remote servers" and "3. Deploy dependencies as well" in your question. You have to have some kind of access to deploy something to some other thing.